# Not getting http response body when using camel producertemplate and http

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I am trying to invoke my simple GET rest service call using producertemplate as specified on http://camel.apache.org/http.html. I have used google.com as an example here. This is from a standalone client not running on any container. What am i not doing right here?

```
SpringCamelContext camelcontext = (SpringCamelContext) springContext.getBean("camelcontextbean");

ProducerTemplate template = camelcontext.createProducerTemplate();
camelcontext.start();
Exchange exchange = template.send("http://www.google.com/search", new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, "hl=en&q=activemq");
            }
   });

   Message out = exchange.getOut();
System.out.println("Response from http template is "+exchange.getOut().getBody());
   System.out.println("status header is "+out.getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE));
```

I dont get any response. The output is:

Response from http template is null

status header is null

Comment: For new visitors: The above code works fine. Looks like workspace issues.

Answer (score 5):

It has to do with the way you are creating the camelContext from Spring because if I remove that and get the *CamelContext* off the *DefaultCamelContext* I don't see an issue:

```
import org.apache.camel.*;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String ... args){
        CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();

        Exchange exchange = template.send("http://www.google.com/search", new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, "hl=en&q=activemq");
            }
        });

        Message out = exchange.getOut();
        System.out.println("Response from http template is "+exchange.getOut().getBody());
        System.out.println("status header is "+out.getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE));
    }

}
```

yields

```
Response from http template is org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream@26659db7
status header is 200
```

Comment: Thanks dimitrisli. I could not spend time to work back on this issue, but your response seems to provide pointers on what i should be debugging. I will debug and update my findings here soon.

Comment: I created the project again and rebuilt and still using the springcamelcontext. It works fine. Something to do with my workspace.

Comment: how to access the data in the stream?  org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream@26659db7? as in if the response is like a json, how to access it

Answer (score 2):

The send method is an in only pattern, you may have more luck using the request method (see the official [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html))

```
Exchange exchange = template.request("http://www.google.com/search", new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, "hl=en&q=activemq");
        }
});
```

Comment: No luck. I had tried that as per the documentation. I get same response.

Comment: Adding to my comment above, as per the documentation template.send is supposed to work with the response being available on the out exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You can access your response via `exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Exchange exchange = template.request("http://www.google.com/search", new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, "hl=en&q=activemq");
        }
});
```

How to call post service if I have body and headers.