# Spring Boot Camel Route - get data from rest endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I want to create camel route in Spring Boot (2.1.1) project to get the data from some (rest) endpoint (http://localhost:8080/getAllUsers) and to send that data to activeMq.

I have tried with timer data to send it on activeMq and to consume it and it is working. But I have problem with collecting data from endpoint.

I have tried several things but no success. This is what I have tried.

In this example I am not sending the data to ActiveMq, I just want to see the response...

```
public void createNewRoute() {
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

try {
  ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
  context.start();

  Exchange exchange = template.request("http://localhost:8080/getAllUsers",
      new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        }
      });

  if (null != exchange) {
    Message out = exchange.getOut();
    int responseCode = out.getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, Integer.class);
    System.out.println("Response: " + String.valueOf(responseCode));
  }

  Thread.sleep(1000 * 3);
  context.stop();
} catch (Exception ex) {
  System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
}

System.out.println("DONE!!");
 }
```

Another route:

```
 from("servlet://localhost:8080/getAllUsers").to("activemq://all-users");
```

And another:

```
 rest("//localhost:8080/getAllUsers")
 .get().consumes("application/json")
 .to("activemq://all-users");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go with your second example:

```
from("timer://test?repeatCount=1").routeId("newRoute")
    .streamCaching()
    .process(exchange -> exchange.getIn()
        .setBody(exchange.getIn()
            .getBody()))
    .marshal()
    .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
    .to("http://localhost:8080/getAllUsers")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "This is my body: ${body}")
    .to("activemq:queue://new-queue");
```

This will trigger it once.

Comment: This works. Thank you. But how can I call it (trigger it) on user request not on timer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this without context.start() ....

```
   CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
    ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();

    Exchange exchange = template.send("http://localhost:8080/getAllUsers", new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {}
    });

    Message out = exchange.getOut();
```

Comment: Yes i tested it with curl, swagger, chrome, postman and etc... And its giving ok response.

Comment: Try removing context.start();
Here was someone with the same problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306211/not-getting-http-response-body-when-using-camel-producertemplate-and-http

Comment: I have changed my method as yours and now it gives Message[]... I think its same.

Comment: weird.
maybe set  exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, ""); in process method?

Comment: Still the same... Maybe the message is empty because the response is Array from JsonObjects?

Comment: Now I`ve got: Response from http template is org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream@7e1ffe70

Comment: Found this one. Maybe you are right
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51018993/accessing-data-from-json-body-inside-apache-camel

Comment: I saw this but the answer is to create pojo class like the object in the response and in my case that is not a solution. What If I need to make 20 different routes to 20 different endpoints, then I will need to create 20 pojos...

Comment: Maybe use map for serialization?
Found this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085921/unmarshal-json-to-map-list-of-strings

Comment: I could not implement unmarshall in that route. I have made it in from->unmarshal->to (route) which is second in my example and still nothing..

Comment: Its not that, I have tested it with another endpoint which gives response String and its same. 
Response from http template is org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream@6fa2448b

Answer (score 1):

The http components are streaming based, so you can ask Camel to give you the response as string instead.

```
String s = exchange.getMessage().getBody(String.class);
```

See more in these links

- http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching
- http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html